# Какие исключения Java возвращают в сообщении "n/a"?

Tags: java, исключения

Какие исключения в Java 1.7 возвращают через ex.getMessage() сообщение "n/a"?
Есть подозрения на NumberFormatException, но проблема возникла удалённо и у себя данную проблему не продебажить.

Comment: Исключения любого типа можно выбрасывать с произвольными сообщениями. По сообщению тип определить нельзя. Нужно логировать тип исключения и трассировку стека. Либо анализировать код логически и воспроизводить ошибку.

Comment: Проблема как раз в том, что на нашем проекте два стенда: тестовый и продакшн, на тесте всё работает просто отлично, а на проде валится, хотя код везде одинаковый.

Comment: Видимо на проде что-то происходит по другому. Выводите в логи полную трассировку стека, а не просто `ex.getMessage`. Зачем гадать?

Comment: На такой полицейский разворот нужно согласовывать установку экстренного билда, а это только в самом последнем случае. Бюрократия, знаете ли...

Comment: Понимаю и искренне сочувствую! Я лишь написал, что угадать ошибку по сообщению в общем случае нельзя. Мои варианты (вывод расширенной информации по исключению, воспроизведение ошибки на стенде) могут быть неприменимы, но других я не вижу.

Comment: `NumberFormatException` возвращает сообщение вида `For input string: {строка}`, где `{строка}` - то, что пытались распарсить. Скорее всего `N/A` - это как раз и есть та строка, которую не получается преобразовать в число.

Comment: тогда бы было "For input string: n/a"
А e.getMessage() выдает просто "n\a".

Comment: Классы из `com.sun.org.apache.xerces` нигде не используете?

Comment: Используем много где, спасибо за подсказку, буду рыть в данном направлении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение стало весьма необычным, но сообщение n/a трактуется как not available, такие сообщения могут выбрасываться несколькими исключениями, в том числе

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException
```

Сообщение n/a выкидывается, если к примеру, как возникло в данном случае, величина поля в таблице меньше вводимых значений.